# Plotly Dendrograms: How do you get the actual Clusters?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, hierarchical-clustering, plotly-python, dendrogram

I have created a dendrogram using Plotly (Python) and displayed it successfully:

```
fig = ff.create_dendrogram(dmatrix, orientation='left', labels=labels, linkagefun=lambda x: sch.linkage(x, "average"),)
```

However, I can't find any  way to retrieve the actual cluster assignments from the returned **fig** object.
Looking into the source code of Plotly I found that only the plot data (**dendrogram.data**) and layout information (**dendrogram.layout**) are retained from the clustering process, while the actual wrapped clustering object (**dendrogram**) is discarded:

```
dendrogram = _Dendrogram(
    X,
    orientation,
    labels,
    colorscale,
    distfun=distfun,
    linkagefun=linkagefun,
    hovertext=hovertext,
    color_threshold=color_threshold,
)

return graph_objs.Figure(data=dendrogram.data, layout=dendrogram.layout)
```

Is there a way to retrieve the cluster assignments?

Comment: The [official reference](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.figure_factory.create_dendrogram.html) says it wraps scipy, so I guess you can pull out the cluster values by using `from scipy.cluster import hierarchy;Z = hierarchy.linkage(dmatrix, 'single')`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing. I had to use the exact same settings I used in plotly and how plotly does it internally in order to get the exact same clustering solution.